# Eliminate NULLs rather than hide NULLs? How?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

NULL values have always causing me trouble. Both when calculating and comparing.

The normal way is to "hide" NULLs by coalesce(col,'') or by CASE WHEN ISNULL() etc. Not much about "eliminating" NULLs. I know that NULL has its value, but I have had more problem than gain of them historically.

First: Is there a way to permanently get rid of NULLs automatically? Pseudocode:

```
Update table set null2empty(*)
```

Second: Is there trick to automatically never save NULLs? I guess that constraints causes more problem than the NULLs?

Third: If I cannot get rid of the NULLs in a simple way globally. As this query is beyond my capacity I have no idea to skip comparing NULL with "empty":

```
SELECT skeys(h1-h2) from
(SELECT hstore(t.*) as h1 from table t where id=’1’) h1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT hstore(t.*) as h2 from table t where id=’2’) h2
```

Thank you in advance for any clue or advise!

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up a trigger.

Comment: In order to eliminate existing NULLs or avoiding NULLs?

Answer (score 0):

Define your columns as `NOT NULL`.

For existing tables:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET mycolumn = '' WHERE mycolumn IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN mycolumns DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

There is no global way to say "take all nullable columns, replace null with an empty placeholder value, and make them `not null`". You could write a PL/PgSQL procedure to do that if you wanted, but it's not simple for columns of non-string types. What's the placeholder for `date` for example? You can't use an "empty" value.